# The Word Game, I'm test running on you guys

Tags: riddle, knowledge, wordplay

So every year I've been doing this "Word Game" in which I write a riddle or ask a question and I ask my friends to answer it. My sister claims it too hard. Here it is:

> Who am I?
>
> I am but a panda.
>
> But I don’t see all black and white.
>
> I’m of inception,
>
> Here Five and Eight is equal to two-ninths.

(These two lines gives you the answer if you need help)

> I’m one of Gracelyn’s favorite book characters,
>
>  And I certainly do have a lot of Grace.

Comment: Sorry this riddle probably sucks.

Comment: Anything to do with Pittacus Lore's series?

Comment: Who are you? You are a panda.

Comment: Nah, it's not any of the books I've mentioned in my profile… that would be too easy… :)

Comment: For some insight as to why people might think this is hard is because it is trivia. You can only know of the answers existence if you know of about a certain subject, and even then you need to still think about the original riddle and put the two together.....(I dislike trivia questions because I rarely know of the answers existence :{ )

Comment: This is similar to "guess the number that I'm thinking of betwee 1 and 1000". Without knowing anything about you, how are we supposed to know who your favourite book characters are?

Comment: @Ian MacDonald obviously, there are a couple of clues as well...

Comment: The hint doesn't require any outside knowledge at all whatsoever, if anybody is wondering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't read the book, but this might be

> Prince Po from the book [Graceling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graceling)

Who am I?
I am but a panda.

> He shares a name with the main character from the movie "Kung Fu Panda"

But I don’t see all black and white.

> He is blinded during the story

I’m of inception,

> He can see into people's minds, similar to the movie "Inception"

Here Five and Eight is equal to two-ninths.

> I didn't get this one, but Gracelyn Rioux has clarified that this means in the word "Inception", the fifth and eight letters make up two ninths of the entire word, spelling "Po"

I’m one of Gracelyn’s favorite book characters,
And I certainly do have a lot of Grace.

> He's a book character and he has a "Grace", which is capitalised in the wikipedia article similarly to how it is in the clue.

Comment: The five and eight clue directly connects with the one immediately preceding it.

Comment: @Gracelyn Rioux does that mean this answer is wrong or that you're looking for all the lines to be understood?

Comment: I would think the answer looks right, personally...  I feel like Gracelyn is just picky. :)

Comment: Nice job! Only my sister and friend got this one. The "Here Five and Eight is equal to two-ninths" means that in the word "Inception", the fifth and eight letters make up two ninths of the entire word, spelling "Po"

Comment: I got it by googling "book character has a lot of grace" and noticing that one of the results capitalised the word "Grace" the same way the clue did

Comment: Argh! I've read those books - I should've been able to get this one. Nice one, Player One and @GracelynRioux! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Partial Answer

I must admit I Googled a lot to arrive at this point.

> By checking the OP's profile, I deducted that the character is from one of her books that she mentioned.
>
> So I googled each of the books to see if there is any character who might fit the description.
>
> Found Percy Jackson novels has some characters who are named Grace (Beryl Grace, Jason Grace, Thalia Grace)

That's as far as I've gone.

Comment: It is a book, but unfortunately not one of those.